# How to save to localstorage by date?

Tags: javascript, local-storage

Okay so I am trying to add a functionality to an app. It is an app for booking cinema tickets and it looks like this [image: look] . You can also change dates like [image: this] . What I am trying to do here is to save to local storage the data(booked seats) for each date individually and restore it when I switch back to the date. Any idea how to do that? Thanks

here is the codepen: https://codepen.io/janek-linhart/pen/xxEzGrO

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.13.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-Bfad6CLCknfcloXFOyFnlgtENryhrpZCe29RTifKEixXQZ38WheV+i/6YWSzkz3V" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Movie Seat Booking</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>


 <script>
  var dateToday = new Date();
  var searchMaxDate = "1w";
  $(function() {
   $( "#dtb_yr" ).datepicker({
    minDate: dateToday,
    maxDate: searchMaxDate,
     onSelect: function(d,i){
          if(d !== i.lastVal){
              $(this).change();
          }
     }
});
 });
 </script>
</head>
<body>
    
    <h1>VanillaJS cinema</h1>

    <div class="wrapper">

        <div class="movie-selection">

            <div class="movie-container">
                <label>Select date</label>
                
                <input type="text" name="dtb_yr" id="dtb_yr" placeholder="Select Date" />
                
                <label>Select the movie</label>
               
                <select id="movie">
                    <option id="selection" value="0">Press to select...</option>
                    <option id="avengers" value="10">Tron: Legacy-start:10:00</option>
                    <option id="joker" value="12">The Internship-start:12:00</option>
                    <option id="toystory" value="8">The Social Network-start:14:00</option>
                    <option id="lionking" value="9">The Matrix-start:16:00</option>
                    <option id="endgame" value="5">The Swiss army man-start:18:00</option>
                    <option id="infinitywar" value="4">Green Book-start:20:00</option>
                </select>
            </div>

            <div class="summary-container">
                <div class="items">
                    <p class="text seats-number">Number of seats</p>
                    <p class="text seats-premium-number">Premium seats</p>
                    <p class="text ticket-price">Ticket price</p>
                    <p class="text ticket-premium-price">Ticket premium price</p>
                    <p class="text total-price">Total price</p>
                </div>
                <div class="totals">
                    <p class="number seats-number" id="count">0</p>
                    <p class="number seats-premium-number" id="countpremium">£0</p>
                    <p class="number ticket-price" id="price">£0</p>
                    <p class="number ticket-premium-price" id="premiumprice">£0</p>
                    <p class="number total-price" id="total">£0</p>
                </div>
                
            </div>

            <div class="commands-container">
                <button id="resetselection"><span style="color: tomato;"><i class="fa fa-times-circle"></i></span>
                     Reset</button>
                <button id="confirmselection"><span style="color:limegreen;"><i class="fa fa-pound-sign"></i></span> Pay</button>
            </div>
    
        </div>
        
        <div class="seat-selection">
            <div class="cinema-container">
            
                <div class="screen" id="screen"></div>
        
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="seat"></div>
                    <div class="seat"></div>
                    <div class="seat"></div>
                    <div class="seat"></div>
                    <div class="seat"></div>
                    <div class="seat"></div>
                    <div class="seat"></div>
                    <div class="seat"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="seat"></div>
                    <div class="seat"></div>
                    <div class="seat"></div>
                    <div class="seat"></div>
                    <div class="seat"></div>
                    <div class="seat"></div>
                    <div class="seat"></div>
                    <div class="seat"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="seat"></div>
                    <div class="seat"></div>
                    <div class="seat"></div>
                    <div class="seat"></div>
                    <div class="seat"></div>
                    <div class="seat"></div>
                    <div class="seat"></div>
                    <div class="seat"></div>
                </div>

                <!-- Premium seats central -->
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="seat"></div>
                    <div class="seat"></div>
                    <div class="seat premium-seat"></div>
                    <div class="seat premium-seat"></div>
                    <div class="seat premium-seat"></div>
                    <div class="seat premium-seat"></div>
                    <div class="seat"></div>
                    <div class="seat"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="seat"></div>
                    <div class="seat"></div>
                    <div class="seat premium-seat"></div>
                    <div class="seat premium-seat"></div>
                    <div class="seat premium-seat"></div>
                    <div class="seat premium-seat"></div>
                    <div class="seat"></div>
                    <div class="seat"></div>
                </div>

                <!-- Normal seats -->
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="seat"></div>
                    <div class="seat"></div>
                    <div class="seat"></div>
                    <div class="seat"></div>
                    <div class="seat"></div>
                    <div class="seat"></div>
                    <div class="seat"></div>
                    <div class="seat"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="seat"></div>
                    <div class="seat"></div>
                    <div class="seat"></div>
                    <div class="seat"></div>
                    <div class="seat"></div>
                    <div class="seat"></div>
                    <div class="seat"></div>
                    <div class="seat"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="seat"></div>
                    <div class="seat"></div>
                    <div class="seat"></div>
                    <div class="seat"></div>
                    <div class="seat"></div>
                    <div class="seat"></div>
                    <div class="seat"></div>
                    <div class="seat"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        
            <div class="showcase">
                <ul class="row-showcase">
                    <li>
                        <div class="seat"></div>
                        <small>Free</small>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <div class="seat premium-seat"></div>
                        <small>Premium seat</small>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="row-showcase">
                    <li>
                        <div class="seat selected"></div>
                        <small>Selected</small>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <div class="seat occupied"></div>
                        <small>Occupied</small>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

script.js

```
const cinemacontainer = document.querySelector('.cinema-container');
const seats = document.querySelectorAll('.row .seat:not(.occupied)');
const count = document.getElementById('count');
const total = document.getElementById('total');
const movieSelect = document.getElementById('movie');
const dateSelect = document.getElementById('dtb_yr');

let movieList = [];

getMovieList();
checkStorage();


// #########################################################################
// FUNCTIONS
// #########################################################################

// CHECK STORAGE
function checkStorage() {

    const movieIndex = +localStorage.getItem('selectedMovieIndex');

    if (!(movieIndex === 0)) {
        if (localStorage.getItem('selectedSeats_'+movieList[movieIndex][1]) === null) {
            resetSeatGrid();
            localStorage.setItem('selectedSeats_'+movieList[movieIndex][1], '');
            localStorage.setItem('selectedPremiumSeats_'+movieList[movieIndex][1], '');
            localStorage.setItem('occupiedSeats_'+movieList[movieIndex][1], '');
        }
        else {
            resetSeatGrid();
            populateUI();
            updateSelectedCountAndTotal();
        }
    }
    else if (movieIndex === 0) {
        resetSeatGrid();
        document.getElementById('screen').innerHTML = '';
    }
    
}

// ----------------------
// GET MOVIE LIST
function getMovieList() {
    for(i=0;i<movieSelect.options.length;i++) {
        movieList.push([movieSelect.options[i].text, movieSelect.options[i].id]);
    }
}

// ----------------------
// SET MOVIE DATA
// Save selected movie index and price
function setMovieData(movieIndex, moviePrice) {
    localStorage.setItem('selectedMovieIndex', movieIndex);
    localStorage.setItem('selectedMoviePrice', moviePrice);
}

// ----------------------
// POPULATE UI
// Get data from localStorage and populate the UI
function populateUI() {

    if (localStorage.length > 0) {

        const movieIndex = localStorage.getItem('selectedMovieIndex');

        if (movieIndex !== null) {
            movieSelect.selectedIndex = movieIndex;
        }

        if (!(localStorage.getItem('selectedSeats_'+movieList[movieIndex][1]) === null) || localStorage.getItem('selectedSeats_'+movieList[movieIndex][1]).length > 0) {

            const selectedSeats = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('selectedSeats_'+movieList[movieIndex][1]));

            if (selectedSeats !== null && selectedSeats.length > 0) {
                seats.forEach((seat, index) => {
                    if(selectedSeats.indexOf(index) > -1) {
                        seat.classList.add('selected');
                    }
                });
            }
        }

        if (!(localStorage.getItem('selectedPremiumSeats_'+movieList[movieIndex][1]) === null) || localStorage.getItem('selectedPremiumSeats_'+movieList[movieIndex][1]).length > 0) {
            
            const selectedPremiumSeats = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('selectedPremiumSeats_'+movieList[movieIndex][1]));

            if (selectedPremiumSeats !== null && selectedPremiumSeats.length > 0) {
                seats.forEach((seat, index) => {
                    if(selectedPremiumSeats.indexOf(index) > -1) {
                        seat.classList.add('selected-premium');
                    }
                });
            }
        }

        if (!(localStorage.getItem('occupiedSeats_'+movieList[movieIndex][1]) === null) || localStorage.getItem('occupiedSeats_'+movieList[movieIndex][1]).length > 0) {
            
            const occupiedSeats = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('occupiedSeats_'+movieList[movieIndex][1]));
            
            if (occupiedSeats !== null && occupiedSeats.length > 0) {
                seats.forEach((seat, index) => {
                    if(occupiedSeats.indexOf(index) > -1) {
                        seat.classList.add('occupied');
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
};

// ----------------------
// UPDATE SELECTED COUNT AND TOTAL
// Update total and count
function updateSelectedCountAndTotal() {

    if (localStorage.length > 0) {

        const selectedSeats = document.querySelectorAll('.row .seat.selected');
        const selectedSeatsPremium = document.querySelectorAll('.row .seat.selected-premium');
        const occupiedSeats = document.querySelectorAll('.row .seat.occupied');

        // Copy selected seats into an array
        // Map through that array
        // Return a new array of indexes
        const seatsIndex = [...selectedSeats].map((seat) => [...seats].indexOf(seat));
        const seatsPremiumIndex = [...selectedSeatsPremium].map((seat) => [...seats].indexOf(seat));
        const occupiedIndex = [...occupiedSeats].map((seat) => [...seats].indexOf(seat));

        const movieIndex = localStorage.getItem('selectedMovieIndex');

        localStorage.setItem('selectedSeats_'+movieList[movieIndex][1], JSON.stringify(seatsIndex));
        localStorage.setItem('selectedPremiumSeats_'+movieList[movieIndex][1], JSON.stringify(seatsPremiumIndex));
        localStorage.setItem('occupiedSeats_'+movieList[movieIndex][1], JSON.stringify(occupiedIndex));

        const selectedSeatsCount = selectedSeats.length;
        const selectedPremiumSeatsCount = selectedSeatsPremium.length;

        count.innerText = selectedSeatsCount;
        countpremium.innerText = selectedPremiumSeatsCount;

        const moviePrice = +localStorage.getItem('selectedMoviePrice');
        price.innerText = "£" + moviePrice.toFixed(2);
        premiumprice.innerText = "£" + (moviePrice * 1.25).toFixed(2);

        total.innerText = "£" + (+(selectedSeatsCount * moviePrice + moviePrice * 1.25 * selectedPremiumSeatsCount)).toFixed(2);

        if (!(movieIndex == 0)) {
            document.getElementById('screen').innerHTML = movieList[movieIndex][0];
        }

    }

};


// #########################################################################
// EVENT LISTENER
// #########################################################################

// ----------------------
// SELECT A MOVIE
// Movie select event
movieSelect.addEventListener('change', (e) => {

    setMovieData(e.target.selectedIndex, e.target.value);
    checkStorage();
    
    ticketPrice = +e.target.value;

    updateSelectedCountAndTotal();
});

$('#dtb_yr').change(function(){
    resetSelection()
    resetSeatGrid()
    updateSelectedCountAndTotal()
    
    
});

  
// ----------------------
// SELECT A SEAT
// Seat click event
cinemacontainer.addEventListener('click', (e) => {

    if(e.target.classList.contains('seat') && !e.target.classList.contains('occupied') && !e.target.classList.contains('premium-seat') && !(movieSelect.options[movieSelect.selectedIndex].id === 'selection')) {
        // with toggle it is possible to apply and remove the class quickly
        e.target.classList.toggle('selected');
        updateSelectedCountAndTotal();
    }

    if(e.target.classList.contains('premium-seat') && !e.target.classList.contains('occupied') && !(movieSelect.options[movieSelect.selectedIndex].id === 'selection')) {
        e.target.classList.toggle('selected-premium');
        updateSelectedCountAndTotal();
    }

});

// ----------------------
// RESET SELECTION
// Cancel selected seats
document.getElementById('resetselection').addEventListener('click', function() {
    resetSelection();
    updateSelectedCountAndTotal();
});

// ----------------------
// CONFIRM SELECTION
// Confirms selected seats and block them
document.getElementById('confirmselection').addEventListener('click', function() {
    confirmSelection();
    updateSelectedCountAndTotal();
});


// #########################################################################
// SELECTION FUNCTIONS
// #########################################################################

function resetSelection() {
    seats.forEach(seat => {
        if (seat.classList.contains('selected')) {
            seat.classList.remove('selected');
        }
        if (seat.classList.contains('selected-premium')) {
            seat.classList.remove('selected-premium');
        }
    });
};

function resetSeatGrid() {
    resetSelection();
    seats.forEach(seat => {
        if (seat.classList.contains('occupied')) {
            seat.classList.remove('occupied');
        }
    });
};

function confirmSelection() {
    seats.forEach(seat => {
        if (seat.classList.contains('selected')) {
            seat.classList.add('occupied');
            seat.classList.remove('selected');
        }
        if (seat.classList.contains('selected-premium')) {
            seat.classList.add('occupied');
            seat.classList.remove('selected-premium');
        }
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

create an object array and save it to storage.

```
var dataToStore = [];
dataToStore.push({day:"20210106", premiumSeats:[2], normalSeats:[2,4,9] });
dataToStore.push({day:"20210105", premiumSeats:[4,7], normalSeats:[4,5,7,14] });

localStorage.setItem("myAllData", JSON.stringify(dataToStore));
```

when you need the specific day data;

```
var myAllData = localStorage.getItem("myAllData");
var dayData = JSON.parse(myAllData).filter(x => x.day == "20210105"); //IE may throws error on lambda
```